# Remove Item from Kendo Grid without refreshing datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

I have a Kendo Grid where one of the columns is a Boostrap progress bar. It is animated and represents a file upload.(the width value is modified with angular)

Once the item is done I remove the item with the remove function like this"

```
Grid.dataSource.remove(item);
```

However all the rest of items in the grid get refreshed somehow and the progress bars go back to zero and get refilled. So if an item in the list is at 70%, it will go back to zero and get refilled quickly.

It happens very fast in a split second but it just looks bad.

[image: Progress Bar]

Is it possible to stop the refresh of other items and only remove a single item in the datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what has been working for me, as long as you have selected the row you want to remove.

```
var grid= $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.removeRow(grid.select());
```

If you have not manually selected it, you can do it via js:

```
grid.select(-1); //this cleans the current selection
var tr = $("#Grid").find("tbody").find("tr")[index]; // 0 based index of the item you want to select
grid.select(tr);
```

Try that and let me know if it helped